# Check if the date of a timezone is passed current time

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone, pytz

I receive time in the format `12:00` and I also have a timezone in the format `<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' PMT+0:09:00 STD>`. I want to see, if this date is already passed current time in that timezone.

My current timezone may be different from the timezone I receive, so I use the following:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
d = parse("14:39").replace(tzinfo=tz)
now = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
print (d - now).total_seconds()
```

Even though the current time in Paris is 14:39, I still get 6600 seconds. I also tried `now = datetime.datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz`), but I get -3600 seconds.

What I want is having time in a specified timezone, check whether it passed or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

tz = tz.gettz('Europe/Paris')
now = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=tz)
d = datetime.strptime("{0}/{1}/{2} 14:39".format(now.year,now.month,now.day), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M").replace(tzinfo=tz)

print (d-now).total_seconds()
```

I keep the current time in **now**, in the Europe/Paris  timezone, and also create **d** in the same timezone. If their difference is negative the date is already passed current time in that timezone.

Comment: What if the now's day has changed?

Comment: Well I didn't understand perfectly from your question, but I guess you should reinitialize now every time you do this, so you can recalculate with the current time.